# Python - How to check if requests installed correctly

Tags: python, plugins, python-requests

So i'm using `import requests` in one of my python scripts but i keep getting a large error that looks to be the `.get()` method that i'm using out of the requests isn't there, or it wasn't installed correctly, now even when i try `pip` to get to the help menu it isnt doing it correctly. I followed the directions https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html here, but even the `python get-pip.py` won't work? I feel like i am missing something very simple.. any advice? i know i have python installed correctly because `whereis python` comes back correctly with the location.

```
cambria@Vayne:~$ pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 521, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2632, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2312, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2318, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

any light on this would help, i have been trying to fix this for a couple days now but im just not sure what isn't installed correctly or what i'm missing

thank you very much! sorry if i'm not clear enough english is my second language

Comment: What does `import requests; print requests.__file__` produce?

Comment: `/home/cambria/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.pyc` that means it is installed correct?

Comment: That does look like a proper installation, but an import from the `requests/compat.py` module fails. It may be that `pip` bundles their own copy or that it gets confused between versions.

Comment: what would be my best course of action? @MartijnPieters check the requests version i installed somehow?

Comment: If this was my system I'd go and debug (edit files inserting a `pdb.set_trace()` breakpoint) to see what the hell is going on and what the 'normal' imports look like. But that requires more access to your system than you probably would give me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It probably your internet connection. Try pip install requests if you haven't or not sure you installed it and turn on your internet.

It worked for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).